# Passing variable value from react constructor to nodeJS backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, router

Is it possible to post variable values from a react constructor to nodejs backend. We want to post certain data as and when the page is loaded to nodejs and perform some function in the backend.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const tokenFetch = localStorage.getItem("JWT");
        const nameFetch = localStorage.getItem("Name");
        this.state = {
            userLoggedIn,
            name: nameFetch,
            tokenFetch: tokenFetch
        };
}
```

here in the constructor we want to post name and tokenFetch to backend.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us some code with what you've tried so far.

Comment: The issue is that generally we post data from forms, and here we want to post data from constructors. Hence, there is no code written currently for the issue.
Update: Check the OP for code

Comment: try making a request (get, post ...) to the backend

Comment: @YashKumarVerma is right, but don't use `request`, use `axios` from frontend applications, `request` is best used from backend calls.

Comment: But where do I make the post request, that is the question here. Since there is no form involved.

Comment: @darklightcode by request, i was referring to a HTTP request, not the module.

Comment: Can someone share a sample snippet, I'm still unable to post from within constructor

Comment: read: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-http-requests-like-a-pro-with-axios/

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/whereYouWantToSendData',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Finn',
    lastName: 'Williams'
  }
});

Comment: Put the code from Yash in `componentDidMount` method in your top level component. We don't know the structure of your app, so that would be the safest bet. Best regards

Comment: and how to I use it in nodejs, once it is posted?

Comment: I don't want to mount the component, the idea is that the data will be fetched from localstorage, it will be sent to backend for valdiation,once validated a bit will be returned back to the page and if the bit is false, the components will not render. Hence we want to do it in constructor

Answer (score 0):

Deciding if some elements should render based on the response from an HTTP request in the `constructor` is a bad idea. You don't want your page to 'hang' because the request takes more time than you anticipated.

You should instead add a `boolean` flag to the state in the `constructor`, and based on this flag render the elements you want or don't want to render. Then, you can execute your HTTP request in the `componentDidMount` method, and then change the flag:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const tokenFetch = localStorage.getItem("JWT");
    const nameFetch = localStorage.getItem("Name");
    this.state = {
      responseFromServerReceived: false,
      userLoggedIn,
      name: nameFetch,
      tokenFetch: tokenFetch
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/whereYouWantToSendData',
      data: { firstName: this.state.nameFetch, token: this.state.tokenFetch }
    }).then(response => {
      // Whatever you want to do with the response;
      this.setState({ responseFromServerReceived: true });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const elementToRender = this.state.responseFromServerReceived
      ? <h1>Hello, the response of the server was received.</h1>
      : <h1>Hello, the response of the server was NOT received yet.</h1>;

    return (
      <div>
        {elementToRender}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay I'll try this on the front end, can you also share a snippet on how the request will be handled at the backend Nodejs?

Comment: it gives me Post 404 in console

Comment: What value did you pass for `url`? If you did not change it, it will of course result in a `404` status, which means that the resource was not found. If you want help regarding the backend, you will need to create a new question as it is not in scope of this one.

Comment: I passed "/user"

Comment: What changes do I make on the server side

Comment: I'm doing
`
axios.post('/user').then(resp => {
    console.log("Hello world");
});
`
on my server side

Comment: Look, the question you asked was about how to handle this in the frontend. You now have a solution for that, as you can see that it is able to call your backend, and the desired elements will render based on whether the request has been executed or not. To get help regarding the backend, you should close this question and create a new question for the backend.